# how to improve autosuggest/complete in blackberry + java

Tags: blackberry

I am facing lot of issues while implement the auto suggest :I will tell you my issues .

1) Focus is always comes on auto suggest /complete field.First there is button .But focus is also on autosuggest field as shown in figure

[image]

2) When I write **m** on auto suggest field monday is display when I click the track pad it display monday on autosuggest field But Monday of pop up is not hide.

[image]

3) what is this encircle .How to change is gray color (or remove this color).some times it display on whole field and some time on half field

[image]

4) I just want a auto suggest with fix width not whole width .Like this on a screen with black background and autosuggest (edit field have white background no gray when focus comes on auto suggest)
[image]

Example

```
Label  Auto suggest

Days   Auto-complete of days

public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements JsonObserver
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("Drop-down List Demo"); 

        VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setExtent(maxWidth, maxHeight/2);
            }
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                graphics.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight()/2);
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        };

        vfm.add(new ButtonField("add"));

        BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
        String[] days = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
filterList.addDataSet(1,days,"days",BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);

        AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList);
        vfm.add(autoCompleteField);
        vfm.add(new ButtonField("addpppp"));

        add(vfm);

      }

}
```